# Google Analytics Click Button Tracking Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I'd like to track clicks on the send button of the contact form on my Contacts page and have it as a Goal on my Google Analytics account.

Since I use a wordpress theme that has its own contact form, to do so, I've opened the lab_contact_form.php in the editor and added this code to the button:

```
onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact', eventAction: 'ContactRequest'});
```

So the button now looks like this:

```
<!-- row -->
<button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary send" onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact', eventAction: 'ContactRequest'});>
<span class="pre-submit"><?php echo esc_html($submit_title); ?></span>
<span class="success-msg"><?php echo strip_tags($submit_success, '<strong><span><em>'); ?> <i class="flaticon-verification24"></i></span>
<span class="loading-bar">
<span></span>
</span>
</button>
```

Then I set up the event in my GA account, specifying Category: Contact and Action: ContactRequest
However, I checked and it doesn't seem to work. GA won't track the event.

Here's the page: http://davidetaraborrelli.it/contatti/

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure there is some insanely stupid syntax​ error in there, since I'm still learning to code!

Thank you!

Kind Regards,
Davide

Comment: Can you specify how you think "it doesn't work"? Are you getting errors, are there no GA hits, etc.

Comment: Sure, sorry for being so generic! What I meant is that GA won't track clicks, like if the event is not triggering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just had a syntax error:

```
<button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary send" onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact', eventAction: 'ContactRequest'});>
```

You need a closing double-quote just before the `>` at the end.

Comment: ugh. Stupid me! Thank you nyuen, I knew it was just a stupid newbie syntax error, I will let you know if Google Analytics will track the hits as soon as possible

Comment: Checked with fresh data and now works perfectly, thank you for helping me out nyuen :)